# BluePrism: How can we identify an element without launching that application from Application Modeller

Tags: blueprism

I have a web application that requires login credentials to reach the target page. I do not have these credentials and currently depending on the Credentials already setup under System-> Security-> Credential of Blue Prism.

I want to add a new element from the target page but cannot attach that page directly since it is launching and asking for credentials.

How can I identify an element from an already open web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "How can I identify an element from an already open web application.", the answer is:

For Internet Explorer: simply attach the browser using the reference to the process name.

Create a "IE - Basic Actions" object, specifying that the application is already running for a process called "iexplore". This would allow you to attach the page and spy it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can. BP needs toLaunch an app to see it(identify its elements). If you open an app "by yourself" then BP wont see it and you wont be able to identify its elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the Web application instead of launching it. When attaching you should do as follows.

1. Read stage, check if you are already connected, if you are, don't do the next part and start working.
2. Navigation stage, attach using either window name or process name normally is the easiest.
3. Set up a retry loop(3 times) so you won't end in an inifite loop. Go to 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to identify the element without launching it through `Blue Prism`. Basically when we do launch the application through `Application Modeller`, it attaches the process to `Blue Prism` instance and we can able to identify the elements.

There are two ways to create application modeller :

```
 1. A Browser which is already running
 2. A browser that is launched from an executable file
```

Based on requirement and the process start point i.e.
If before starting of process, if the application is already launched then the first option is suitable else the second option is suitable
, you may need to select any of the option mentioned above.

The **First option**, will only attach the `Blue Prism` instance to the application's process, and you may identify the element. To use this action you may need to give process name  to which `Blue Prism` instance need to get attach.

The **Second option**, `Blue Prism` will launch the application and it automatically attach the application's process to `Blue prism` instance.